# Copy file from local to AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I'd like to copy local files to an EFS instance using command line.

I was expecting something as simple as : `aws efs cp <my-file> <my-efs:/path>`, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just want to copy the files from local to EFS. The ideal way is to mount the EFS volume in your local machine and copy the files from local to EFS's mount directory

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html) for mounting EFS volume on EC2 instance. you can follow the same steps in your local.

Once you have done with copying unmount the EFS mount.

Comment: What about uploading files to efs without mounting them in EC2 machine? I mean copy files maybe using aws cli tool to upload from on-prem server.